# Convert int array into bufferedImage in java

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedimage, fisheye

I was wondering how i could construct an int array in java into a buffered image. I know you can get an int array in java by doing

```
int[] srcpixels = ((DataBufferInt)in.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

but i dont know how to do it the other way. I need this to apply a fisheye effect to a buffered image which i found out how to do here http://popscan.blogspot.com/2012/04/fisheye-lens-equation-simple-fisheye.html but it only works with int arrays. Please help, thanks.

Comment: is there no `setRaster()`-method?

Answer (score 2):

Use a WritableRaster:

```
final int w = bitmap.getWidth();
final int h = bitmap.getHeight();

final WritableRaster wr = bitmap.getData();
int []data = wr.getPixels(0, 0, w, h, data);

// do processing here

wr.setPixels(0, 0, w, h, data);
```